Получение последнего события в логе без чтения файла. python logging
Используется модуль python logging и лог пишется файл. При каждом запуске программы файл дописывается. В тории можно открывать файл и читать последнюю строку (файл лога может быть большим), но может где-то хранятся в памяти выведенные сообщения (или последнее сообщение), которое было отправлено в лог.

По умолчанию вроде нет такого решения из коробки. Но вы можете написать свой хендлер с таким поведением.
import logging

class LastLogHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.last_log = None

    def emit(self, record):
        self.last_log = self.format(record)

    def get_last_log(self):
        return self.last_log

logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

file_handler = logging.FileHandler('my_log.log')
file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

last_log_handler = LastLogHandler()
last_log_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(last_log_handler)

logger.debug('This is a debug message')
logger.info('This is an info message')
logger.error('This is an error message')

# Получаем последнее сообщение в логе
last_message = last_log_handler.get_last_log()
print('Last log message:', last_message)

=== Дополнение.
import logging

class LastLogHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.last_log_record = None

    def emit(self, record):
        self.last_log_record = record

    def get_last_log_record(self):
        return self.last_log_record

logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

file_handler = logging.FileHandler('my_log.log')
file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

last_log_handler = LastLogHandler()
logger.addHandler(last_log_handler)

logger.debug('This is a debug message')
logger.info('This is an info message')
logger.error('This is an error message')

# Получаем последнее сообщение в логе как объект
last_log_record = last_log_handler.get_last_log_record()
if last_log_record:
    log_time = last_log_record.asctime
    log_level = last_log_record.levelname
    log_message = last_log_record.message

    print(f'Last log time: {log_time}')
    print(f'Last log level: {log_level}')
    print(f'Last log message: {log_message}')
else:
    print('No log record available')


Спасибо! Хороший вариант! Адаптировал код под себя, что бы обрабатывался  уже написанный код для ведения лога.

Как доработать код, что бы получать объект (а не текст) из которого можно выделить время, тип, текст?

@Stanislav дополнил ответ. Посмотрите пожалуйста отличия.

Я думаю вы можете даже разобраться как это работает, обратив внимание на интерполяцию через: "%" - %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s. И наверное можно поглядеть как внутри библиотека работает, так понятнее будет). По анологии вы можете вытащить остальные поля, доступные для форматирования.

Спасибо большое! Все очень доходчиво и понятно )
